# Converting query to lambda expression with joins and where clause

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, lambda

I have this query and I'm having trouble converting into a lambda expression

```
SELECT [dbo].[Prospects].[Id]
  ,[UserId]
  ,[NewId]
  ,[dbo].[Prospects].[Status]
  FROM [dbo].[Prospects]  join [dbo].[User] on [dbo].[User].Id = [dbo].      [Prospects].UserId
  where [dbo].[Prospects].NewId = 3 and [dbo].[User].IsActive = 1
```

This is what i got, but it is not working

```
 var result = Workspace.Prospects.Join
            (Workspace.Users, pros => pros.UserId,
            use => use.Id, (pros, use)
            => new { Prospect = pros, User = use}).Where
            (both => both.User.IsActive == true && both.Prospect.NewId == idVacante)
            .OrderBy(both => both.Prospect.Id).AsEnumerable().ToList();
 List<Prospect> prospects = result.Cast<Prospect>().ToList();
```

Comment: *not working* how? not returning the right results? Not compiling? throwing exceptions?

Comment: Which exception is thrown? Or it just doesn't get the expected rows?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough, I am not getting the expected rows. I need to select the fields correctly. I got this message  Test 'RecruitmentTestLab.TestLab.Prospects<FirefoxDriver>.CheckProspectsVacancies' failed: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`4[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32]' to type 'RecruitmentTestLab.Prospect'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that hard. you can filter the tables before joining them

```
var result = Workspace.Prospects.Where(x=> x.NewId == 3)
                  .Join(Workspace.Users.Where(x => x.IsActive == 1),
                          p => p.UserId,
                          u => u.Id,
                          (p, u) => new { p.Id, p.UserId, p.NewId, p.Status })
```